# write value into the label

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to write value from loaded csv data into the tkinter label. The value from Test_Start should be written into the tk.Label as textvariable.

I tried it this way, i dont get an error, but it will not to be written. With print i get the value in the console.
Here cut-out from the program:

```
class Analysis_frame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.configure(text="Analysis", relief="ridge", font=("Verdana", 10), borderwidth=1, border=3)
        self.Test_Start = tk.StringVar()
        self.Test_Start.trace("w", self.__create_widgets())
        self.__create_widgets()

    def analysis(self):
        global Dur
        global Temp
        global IGSS1
        global IGSS4

        data = pd.read_csv(data_raw, sep=";", skiprows=[0,1], low_memory=False)
        # print(data_raw.columns)

        Test_Start = data.iloc[:,0].values[0]                # test start, csv file as Datum
        Test_End = data.iloc[:,0].values[-1]                 # test stop, csv file as Datum
        Dur = data.iloc[:,2]                                 # test duration in h, csv file as Zeit in Std
        Temp = data.iloc[:,4]                                # test temperature, csv file as Temperatur

        Supply = data.iloc[:,6]                              
        IGSS1 = data.iloc[:,9]                              
        IGSS4 = data.iloc[:,18]                                                           

        print(f"Test started: {Test_Start}", "\n", f"Test end: {Test_End}", "\n")

    def __create_plot(self):
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(facecolor="white")
        ax1.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")
        plt.axhline(y=5, color='b', label='axhline - full height')
        plt.axhline(y=12, color='g', label='axhline - full height')
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        ax1.plot(Dur, IGSS1, label="IGSS1", color="green", linewidth=0.5)
        ax1.plot(Dur, IGSS4, label="IGSS4", color="blue", linewidth=0.5)
        ax2.plot(Dur, Temp, label="Temp", color="red", linewidth=0.8)
        ax1.set_ylabel("Current [mA]")
        ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature [°C]")
        ax1.set_xlabel("Test duration [h]")
        plt.show()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        tk.Label(self, text="Test start: ", font=("Verdana", 8)).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.S)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.Test_Start, font=("Verdana", 8), width=10, relief="ridge", borderwidth=1, border=3).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.S)

        tk.Button(self, text="Get diagram", font=("Verdana", 8), command=self.__create_plot).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.S)

        for widget in self.winfo_children():        # spacings for all widgets within the frame
            widget.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include relevant imports so we can copy this code and run it ourselves without making assumptions about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you variable Test_Start is not attributed on your label function. You just attributed a value to it on def __create_plot(self):

Try doing this:

```
def __create_widgets(self):

    data = pd.read_csv(data_raw, sep=";", skiprows=[0,1], 
    low_memory=False)
    
    Test_Start = data.iloc[:,0].values[0] 

    tk.Label(self, text="Test start: ", font=("Verdana", 
    8)).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.S)
    tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.Test_Start, font=("Verdana", 8), 
    width=10, relief="ridge", borderwidth=1, border=3).grid(column=1, 
    row=0, sticky=tk.S)

    tk.Button(self, text="Get diagram", font=("Verdana", 8), 
    command=self.__create_plot).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.S)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Test_Start = data.iloc[:,0].values[0]`, you're *assigning* that value to `Test_Start`.

After that assignment it's no longer a `tk.StringVar()`, it's just the (I'm assuming) string value from that dataframe.

If you want to update the `StringVar`, you need to use the `set` method:

```
Test_Start.set(data.iloc[:,0].values[0])
```

*CAVEAT*: I wasn't able to run the code you provided, so there may be other issues at play here as well